# Evolution operator for time-dependent Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian, time-evolution

When I studied QM I'm only working with time independent Hamiltonians. In this case the unitary evolution operator has the form $$\hat{U}=e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}Ht}$$ that follows from this equation 
$$
i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}\hat{U}=H\hat{U}.
$$
And in this case, Hamiltonian in Heisenberg picture ($H_{H}$) is just the same as the Hamiltonian in Schrödinger picture ($H_{S}$), i.e. it commutes with $\hat{U}$.
Now I have a Hamiltonian that depends explicitly on time. Specifically,
$$H_{S}=\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega \hat{q}^2-F_0 \sin(\omega_0t)\hat{q}.$$

And in my problem I need to calculate $H_H$ (Hamiltonian in Heisenberg picture).

I've found that differential equation for $\hat{U}$ (I've mentioned about it above.) has generally solution in the form (with $U(0)=1$)
$$U(t)=1+\xi\int\limits_0^t H(t')\,dt'+ \xi^2\int\limits_0^t H(t')\,dt'\int\limits_0^t' H(t'')\,dt''+\xi^3\int\limits_0^t H(t')\,dt'\int\limits_0^t' H(t'')\,dt''\int\limits_0^t'' H(t''')\,dt'''+...$$

So my questions are:

- Is there other ways to calculate $\hat{U}$, could give a link or tell me about them?
- If you know form of the solution for my case, please tell me.
- If you know any articles or papers articles on this topice, please link them to me, too.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to do? Generally this sort of problem is more tractable in the [Interaction Picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture) generated by $H_0 = \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 q^2$, since you already know the eigenstates of $H_0$. Then you can calculate the evolution of observables or states using the [Dyson series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_series), which is essentially what you have calculated. Your perturbation is time-periodic, so you might also find [Floquet theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory) useful.

Comment: Since your Hamiltonian is periodic in time this link might be helpful : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory

Comment: I want to calculate $E=\langle\hat{H}\rangle$ at time $T$ i.e. $\langle \psi(t)|\hat{H}| \psi(t) \rangle$ or in Heisenberg picture $\langle \psi |\hat{H}(t)| \psi \rangle$. For this thing I need evolution operator to calculate $\hat{H(t)}$, as I think.

Comment: Try reading about the Magnus, Fer and Wilcox expansions: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370157308004092 http://repositori.uji.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10234/32076/44627.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: A situation a lot like this is solved in these [lecture notes](https://noppa.oulu.fi/noppa/kurssi/763693s/materiaali/763693S_monqo.pdf#page=17) that might be useful.

Comment: A naïve question: in the above case of a Hamiltonian with a periodic drive, one could just carry out the $t$-integral in the time evolution operator analytically and avoid the time-ordering, etc., correct?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. The series you have there is called [Dyson's series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_series).

First note that the $n$'th term looks like
$$
U_n = \left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\right)^n\int_0^t dt_1 \cdots\int_0^{t_{n-1}} dt_{n} H(t_1)\cdots H(t_n)
$$

The order of the Hamiltonians is important, since we work with operators. Each term in the series possess a nice symmetry, allowing us to write:

\begin{align}
U_n = \left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\right)^n \int_0^t dt_1 \cdots\int_0^{t_{n-1}} dt_{n}\ H(t_1)\cdots H(t_n) =
\frac{\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\right)^n}{n!}\int_0^t dt_1 \cdots\int_0^t  dt_{n} \mathcal{T}\left[H(t_1)\cdots H(t_n)\right]
\end{align}

Two things happened: first, we "overcount" by making the upper limits equal to $t$ on all the integrals. This is compensated by the factor of $\frac{1}{n!}$. You'll need to convince yourself why this factor is needed ;)

Second, by this change of integration area we mess up the ordering of the Hamiltonians in the process. This is where the time-ordering symbol $\mathcal{T}$ comes in. Basically, this operator ensures that the Hamiltonians are always ordered in the correct way. For instance for $n=2$ it operates as

\begin{align}
\mathcal{T}[H(t_1) H(t_2)] = \begin{cases}
H(t_1) H(t_2) & t_1 > t_2\\
H(t_2) H(t_1) & t_1 < t_2
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Putting everything together we have

$$
U(t, t') = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\right)^n}{n!} \int_{t'}^t dt_1 \cdots\int_{t'}^t dt_n \mathcal{T}[H(t_1)\cdots H(t_n)]
$$
Frequently, this is denoted symbolically as

$$
U(t, t') = \mathcal{T}\exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar} \int_{t'}^t H(t_1) dt_1\right)
$$
This notation is understood as representing the power series.

Comment: I think you wanted to write this for time ordering: $ H(t_2) H(t_1)   t_2 > t_1  $ and  $
H(t_1)H(t_2)  t_2 < t_1 $. If I am not wrong.