# What's the evolution of a state under an adiabatic evolution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, time-evolution, adiabatic

For an initial state $|\Psi\rangle_0$ as the ground state of a Hamiltonian $H(0)$, if it undergoes an adiabatic evolution $H(t)$ to reach the ground state $|\Psi\rangle_1$ of $H(1)$.

Then what's the evolution from the state $|\Psi\rangle_0$ and $|\Psi\rangle_1$?

Can the evolution be written in a form given by $H(t)$ something as $exp(-i\int H(t))dt$? If this is the case, then what's the difference between an adiabatic evolution and a non-adiabatic evolution?

Comment: Concerning the second question, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45455/evolution-operator-for-time-dependent-hamiltonian

Comment: @ Adam Thanks. Yes, the time-ordered integration seems to be the solution. But then there is no difference between the adiabatic and the non-adiabatic evolution since this applies to a normal non-adiabatic evolution too. Does the adiabatic evolution is just to control the Hamiltonian $H(t)$ so that the excited state will not be generated during the evolution (or just the evolution is SLOW enough)?

Comment: An adiabatic evolution is just an evolution that is slow enough (and without level crossing) such that in good approximation, the system stays in the instantaneous ground-state of the Hamiltonian.